# delete files on amazon s3 with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-s3, delete-file

I have an asp button, when the button is clicked , i want to delete my files on s3

But when I click the delete button, it just loads.
My web application is just loading without stopping.

what is the cause?

how do i solve it?

My code :

```
public static IAmazonS3 s3Client;
public static readonly RegionEndpoint bucketRegion = RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast1;
public static string bucketName = "myBucket";
public string s3DirectoryName = "myDirectory";

protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(bucketRegion);
        string filename = s3DirectoryName + "tes_folder" + "/" + "tes_file.pdf";
        DeleteObjectNonVersionedBucketAsync(filename).Wait();
    }

    private static async Task DeleteObjectNonVersionedBucketAsync(string filename)
    {
        try
        {
            var deleteObjectRequest = new DeleteObjectRequest
            {
                BucketName = bucketName,
                Key = filename
            };

            Console.WriteLine("Deleting an object");
            await s3Client.DeleteObjectAsync(deleteObjectRequest);
        }
        catch (AmazonS3Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error encountered on server. Message:'{0}' when deleting an object", e.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unknown encountered on server. Message:'{0}' when deleting an object", e.Message);
        }
    }
```

I've also added a postback

```
<Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnDelete"/>
</Triggers>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   public string s3DirectoryName = "myDirectory";
   string filename = s3DirectoryName + "tes_folder" + "/" + "tes_file.pdf";
```

Which is  myDirectorytes_folder/tes_file.pdf

Add "/" before tes_folder